# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::V1::PostsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, activerecord, rails-api

I am trying to follow Rails Todo API Part 1 from egghead.io https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-rails-todo-api-part-1

I am trying to access localhost:3000/api/v1/posts and the page should show the json response of:

```
[]
```

but instead I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::V1::PostsController#show

Couldn't find Post without an ID      

  def show
    respond_with(Post.find(params[:id])) <----- error is here
  end
```

I also tried adding a record which should return the json response of that record but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

I have completed the controller and routes as follows:

app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb

```
 module Api
   module V1
     class PostsController < ApplicationController
       skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
       respond_to :json

       def index
         respond_with(Post.all.order("id DESC"))
       end

       def show
         respond_with(Post.find(params[:id]))
       end

       def create
         @post = Post.new(post_params)
         if @post.save
           respond_to do |format|
             format.json {render :json => @post}
           end
         end
       end

       def update 
         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
         if @post.update(post_params)
           respond_to do |format|
             format.json {render :json => @post}
           end
         end
       end

       def destroy
         respond_with Post.destroy(params[:id])
       end

     private
       def post_params
         params.require(:post).permit(:content)
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

config/routes.rb

```
 WhatRattlesMyCage::Application.routes.draw do
   namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
     namespace :v1 do
       resource :posts
     end
   end
 end
```

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
     api_v1_posts POST   /api/v1/posts(.:format)      api/v1/posts#create {:format=>:json}
 new_api_v1_posts GET    /api/v1/posts/new(.:format)  api/v1/posts#new {:format=>:json}
edit_api_v1_posts GET    /api/v1/posts/edit(.:format) api/v1/posts#edit {:format=>:json}
                  GET    /api/v1/posts(.:format)      api/v1/posts#show {:format=>:json}
                  PATCH  /api/v1/posts(.:format)      api/v1/posts#update {:format=>:json}
                  PUT    /api/v1/posts(.:format)      api/v1/posts#update {:format=>:json}
                  DELETE /api/v1/posts(.:format)      api/v1/posts#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it `resources :posts` in your routes.rb

As it is you have malformed routes and the show method is being called instead of the index method